# Rename standard field name in XML

Tags: column, field-definition, rename

I have a custom content type that inherits from the standard article page CT. In my new content type I would like to use the Contact field that is inherited from the article page but I would like to change the displayname of the field to "Information owner". I would like to do this in the XML-file not in the UI, is that possible?

Best regards,
Niclas

Answer (score 1):

If you define a ListDefinition basen on your content type, you can set your own DisplayName

```
 <Fields>
  <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="New Title" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" />
 </Fields>
```

You can then create a list based on the list definition.

EDIT:

All this is done in Visual Studio of course

Comment: Hi 

Thanks but is there no way of doing this without creating an own list definition? I just would like to change in the XML-files for my custom content type.